# How to insert csv file to firebase?

Tags: javascript, php, firebase

The upload form

```
<form method="post" action="import.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="file" name="file"/>
                        </div>
                    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit_file" value="Submit"/>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

Possible firebase...

```
var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('user');

document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

function submitForm(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var name = getInputVal('name');
  var email = getInputVal('email');
  var phone = getInputVal('phone');

  saveMessage(name, email, phone);

  document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'block';

  setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'none';
  },3000);

  document.getElementById('form').reset();
}

function getInputVal(id){
  return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

function saveMessage(name, email, phone){
  var newMessageRef = messagesRef.push();
  newMessageRef.set({
    name: name,
    email:email,
    phone:phone,
  });
}
```

I know csv file data can be added into mysql but how about firebase? I want to upload excel file data and store in firebase instead of inserting data one by one in web form...Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can load bulk data from JSON to firebase from admin. But yet there is no way to upload bulk data at once using the code. You'll have to use the looping way...

Comment: @Ashok Shah that means firebase only accept json file?

Comment: True, you can sync data from google sheets to firebase db or you have to convert your csv to json file first before you push data to firebase. Firebase accepts only JSON data.